# ksqlDB fails to deserialize JSON key

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb

I'm trying to load data into a ksqlDB source table by using the JDBC Source connector in Kafka Connect. The topic key is a JSON object created from two of the columns. ksqlDB can't deserialize the key and throughs an error. Is it possible to create a source table in ksqlDB with two columns as primary keys that are deserialized from the JSON key?

The connector config is:

```
CREATE SOURCE CONNECTOR IF NOT EXISTS loadshedding_model_source WITH (
  'connector.class'             = 'io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector',
  'connection.url'              = 'jdbc:postgresql://cockroachdb:26257/db',
  'connection.user'             = 'user',
  'connection.password'         = 'password',
  'connection.options'          = '-c multiple_active_portals_enabled=true',
  'topic.prefix'                = 'jdbc_',
  'table.whitelist'             = 'whitelist_table',
  'mode'                        = 'bulk',
  'numeric.mapping'             = 'best_fit',
  "poll.interval.ms"            = 1800000,
  'transforms'                  = 'createKey',
  'transforms.createKey.type'   = 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey',
  'transforms.createKey.fields' = 'c1,c2',
  'topic.creation.default.partitions' = 3,
  'topic.creation.default.replication.factor' = 3
);
```

I create the Kafka key from two columns 'c1' and 'c2' (see transforms config). This works fine and I can see the messages in the topic has a JSON key in the for

```
{
  "c1": "c1v1",
  "c2": "c2": "v1"
}
```

I'm trying to create a SOURCE table in ksqDB with the PRIMARY KEYs as c1 and c2 wit:

```
CREATE SOURCE TABLE whitelist_table (
  C1 VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
  C2 VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
  C3 VARCHAR,
  C4 TIMESTAMP,
  C5 INT
) WITH (
  KAFKA_TOPIC='jdbc_whitelist_table',
  KEY_FORMAT='JSON',
  VALUE_FORMAT='JSON'
)
```

ksqlDB creates the table but can't deserialize the key. I get the following error message:

```
ERROR {"type":0,"deserializationError":{"target":"key","errorMessage":"Failed to deserialize key from topic: jdbc_model_load_shedding. Unrecognized token 'Struct': was expecting ( JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')","recordB64":null,"cause":["Unrecognized token 'Struct': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')"],"topic":"jdbc_whitelist_table"},"recordProcessingError":null,"productionError":null,"serializationError":null,"kafkaStreamsThreadError":null} (processing.CST_WHITELIST_TABLE_11.KsqlTopic.Source.deserializer:44)
```

Comment: You have not defined `value.converter` or `key.converter` in your connector, so what are they set to by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see error mentioning `Struct` token/string, then you are using `StringConverter`, which  will not work for JSON data. You need to set `JsonConverter` for the key/value converter settings in the connector config

Comment: Thanks for the help @OneCricketeer! I've added the following configs to the connector, and all is good now:  'key.converter'='org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter',
  'key.converter.schemas.enable'='false'. I don't know if both are needed tough. Maybe you could edit you answer to include this for other needing help?

Comment: The schema enable setting depends on what the JSON looks like. https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/